# trying to set query.limit(varname) and getting error saying that the 'limit' can only be set to a numeric

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have been working with Parse for some time now with great success.  Recently, I had an issue that pushed me to move to the latest cdn-based javascript API.  Immediately after changing my parse API version (via cdn), I started getting this error, having to do with a simple query.limit(n) setting I have in my code.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught Error: You can only set the limit to a numeric value
at ParseQuery.limit (parse-latest.js:6704)
at ParseTable.render (ParseTable.js:199)
at ParseTable (ParseTable.js:52)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (players.php:137)
at l (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.A (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
```

See ParseTable.js:199 below - Again, this line has worked for months and only went berzerk after the API swapout.

```
},
            render: function(){
                this.spin(true);
                if(!this.DOM){
                    this.init(); // ONE TIME CALL
                }

                this.query.startsWith(this.opts.searchColumn, input)
                this.query.equalTo(this.opts.primaryKeyCloudColumn, this.opts.username)
                alert(this.pageSize);             <--- this returns 10  -----------
                this.query.limit(this.pageSize)   <--- this is line 199 ----

                if(this.page>1)
                    this.query.skip((this.pageSize*this.page)-this.pageSize)
                else 
                    this.query.skip(0) // unsetting skip

                if(this.sortBy)
                    if(this.sortOrder==='ascending')
                        this.query.ascending(this.sortBy)
                    else 
                        this.query.descending(this.sortBy)

                this.query.find({

                    success: function(results) {

                        if(!results.length){
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found that, for some reason, my query.limit(n) value was being received by the called API function as a character string.

I fixed it by using the following -

```
    this.query.limit(Number(this.pageSize));
```

Working fine again.